# Calculate minutes that have passed since the start of the current month

Tags: php

With PHP, how can I the calculate the number of minutes that have passed between now and the beginning of the current month?

```
$to_time = new DateTime();
$from_time = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$diffInSeconds = $to_time->getTimestamp() - $from_time->getTimestamp();
$diffInMinutes = ($diffInSeconds/60);
echo $diffInMinutes;
```

This seems to return the same value at all times during a given day, even after some time has passed.

Comment: Add your code here

Comment: please make effort and research

Comment: @Dylan, Is this answer is helpful for you?

Comment: @Dylan T What have you tried ? Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.try to  Search and research and try writing some code. 
If you then have trouble, you can come back here and ask a proper question, providing [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use Carbon to do it.

```
$start = Carbon::create()->startOfMonth();
$now = Carbon::now();
echo $now->diffInMinutes($start);
```

Test your code at http://phpio.net/tools/carbon

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
 <?php
    $Now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $Start   = date("Y-m-01 00:00:00");
    $today = new DateTime($Now); 
    $MnthStart   = new DateTime($Start);
    $dteDiff  = $MnthStart->diff($today); 
    $dtsDiff = $dteDiff->format("%a");


    echo "Month Start: ".$Start."<br>";
    echo "Today: ".$Now."<br>";
    echo "Days passed: ".$dtsDiff;
    echo "<br>".$dtsDiff." days Total Mins: ".$dtsDiff* 1440 . " Mins"
 ?>
```

***OUTPUT***

```
Month Start: 2016-11-01 00:00:00

Today: 2016-11-15 00:06:51

Days passed: 14

14 days Total Mins: 20160 Mins
```